# Perl String Regular Expression

Tags: regex, perl

i need some help in Perl regular expressions.
I have this string:

```
{
    "ITEM":[
        {
            "-itemID": "1000000" ,
            "-itemName": "DisneyJuniorLA" ,
            "-thumbUrl": "" ,
            "-packageID": "1" ,
            "-itemPrice": "0" ,
            "-isLock": "true" 
        },
        {
            "-itemID": "1000001" ,
            "-itemName": "31 minutos" ,
            "-thumbUrl": "" ,
            "-packageID": "1" ,
            "-itemPrice": "0" ,
            "-isLock": "true" 
        },
        {
            "-itemID": "1000002" ,
            "-itemName": "Plaza Sésamo" ,
            "-thumbUrl": "" ,
            "-packageID": "1" ,
            "-itemPrice": "0" ,
            "-isLock": "true" 
        },
    ]
}
```

The string is in a variable: `$jsonString`

I have another variable: `$itemName`

I want to only keep in `$jsonString` the itemId value that is above itemName (where itemName equals `$itemName`)

I would really appreciate your help. I am really amateur in regular expressions.

Thank you!

Comment: You think regexps are the solution, so now you have two problems...  You should instead simply use a JSON parser on the entire object, and then traverse it to find the desired field.

Comment: I know it's a json and can be accesed differently. I just must solve it with regular expressions.

Comment: no, you really mustn't!

Comment: Is someone holding a gun to your head and forcing you to use a regexp?

Comment: LOL for real Barmar =)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a regular expression to parse JSON.  Use [JSON](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/JSON-2.90/lib/JSON.pm).

Basically :

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use JSON;

my $json_string;
{
    open( my $json_in, "<", 'test.json' );
    local $/;
    $json_string = <$json_in>;
}

my $json = decode_json ( $json_string );

print Dumper \$json;

foreach my $item ( @{  $json -> {'ITEM'} } ) {
     print $item -> {'-itemID'},"\n";
     print $item -> {'-itemName'},"\n";
}
```

But you have to fix your json first. (There's a trailing comma that shouldn't be there. )

JSON is a defined data transfer structure. Whilst you can *technically* treat it as 'plain text' and extract things from the text, that's definitively the wrong way to do things.

It might work fine for a good long time, but if your source program changes a little - and change their output, whilst still sticking to the JSON standard - your code will break unexpectedly, and you may not realise. That can set off a domino effect of breakages, making a whole system or site just crash and burn. And worse yet - the *source* of this crash and burn will be hidden away in some script that hasn't been touched in years, so will be very difficult to fix.

This is one of my pet peeves as a professional sysadmin. Please don't even go there.

Comment: The input JSON is malformed

Comment: Ack yes, so it is. Well, on with plan B.

Comment: No, he have to fix the JSON or what is making this JSON

Comment: Yes, there's an extraneous comma after the last item in the `ITEM` array.

Comment: Also, the string contains utf8.

Comment: @TLP that's perfectly valid in JSON.

Comment: Good catch on the comma. I was getting hung up on the UTF-8 char. (Which should be valid in JSON, so I couldn't see why it didn't work )

Comment: @Alnitak Yes, but what I mean is I get this error `malformed UTF-8 character in JSON string` when I run this code.

Comment: @TLP odd - I _don't_ get that error (Perl 5.18.2 on OS X 10.10)

Comment: @Alnitak I assume you are using the input from the question? It is the `é` character that is messing up. I am using windows 7, perhaps there is some difference there.

Comment: Oh right! That's because it didn't worked! Any way to remove the last comma in my json?

Comment: I get the same UTF-8 error on Windows. Turning _off_ UTF-8 (but ensuring my JSON was saved appropriately, e.g. setting 'save as UTF-8' in TextPad) fixed it :)

Comment: Really like the 'This is one of my pet peeves as a professional sysadmin. Please don't even go there.' sentence. That's my case too

Comment: I thought better of "I will hunt you down". Seemed a bit too dramatic.

Comment: @Sobrique You would think that gvim would handle that automatically. I can't even find anything that refers to utf8 in gvim, notepad or wordpad.

Answer (score 1):

Notwithstanding that your JSON string is very slightly malformed (there's an extra comma after the last element in the array that should be fixed by whoever's generating the "JSON"), attempting to use regexps to handle this just means you now have two problems instead of one.

More specifically, objects within JSON are explicitly *unordered* sets of key/value pairs.  It's perfectly possible that whatever's changing the JSON could be rewritten such that the JSON is *semantically* identical but serialised differently, making anything that relies on the current structure *brittle* and *error prone*.

Instead, use a proper JSON decoder, and then traverse the resulting object hierarchy directly to find the desired element:

```
use JSON;
use utf8;

# decode the JSON
my $obj = decode_json($jsonString);

# get the ITEM array
my $itemRef = $obj->{ITEM};

# find all elements matching the item name
my @match = grep { $_->{'-itemName'} eq $itemName } @{$itemRef};

# extract the item ID
if (@match) {
    my $itemID = $match[0]->{'-itemID'};
    print $itemID;
}
```

Comment: @sputnik there's no I/O in my code, so the `binmode` settings are inappropriate...  The OP already has perfectly good UTF-8.

Comment: `use :utf8` is more about within the perl source, rather than the file IO.

Comment: @Sobrique I didn't complain about that, just the `binmode`.  There's no UTF-8 in my source anyway ;-)

Comment: Any way to remove the last comma in my json?

Comment: @vaspant the comma error needs to be fixed at source, not "fixed up" by the reader

Comment: The point of using things like JSON, is they're a well documented and defined data interchange format. They're effectively database records. But they key point is - the standard allows certain things, and not other things. If you make assumptions about things that are being done in a non-standard way, this falls apart horribly.
Included in that is data structure and delimiters.

Comment: @Sobrique is that intended for the OP or for me?

Comment: Reiterating 'fix at source, don't hack' :).